# Protractor Internet Explorer Slowness

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've been trying to get Internet Explorer 11 to run under Protractor to complete a suite of tests I have for an new AngularJS project.

I'm running under Windows 7 - 64 Bit and have downloaded and installed the Selenium IEDriverServer.exe for 64 Bit.

When I go to launch Protractor and run the scenarios, Internet Explorer comes up and navigates to the page just fine, but when the scenario sends keys to an input field it is extremely slow, like about 15 seconds between each key press. And Selenium is not showing any type of exception being thrown.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and found a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known bug or "issue" (*not* a bug within the IEDriver however):

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3072 (references IE10 but the point & solution is the same fundamentally)

It is explained in the Selenium issue tracker, but the workaround will be to use the 32bit version of the driver. Realistically you don't get "much" from using the explicit 64bit version.

I'd also say you may have further problems with IE11. Selenium doesn't support IE11 fully yet.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6437#c7 (among other issues)

You are probably, long term, better off downgrading to IE10 and using the 32bit driver.