# How can i improve the script execution speed on IE browser using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am using environment - 
PROTRACTOR Version -- 3.3.0
Node.js Version    -- 6.0.0
Jasmin Framework   -- 2.0
npm Version        -- 3.8.6

The scenario sends keys to an input field it is extremely slow, like about 15 seconds between each key press. 
How come i improve the script execution speed on IE browser using Protractor?

Comment: Use the 32bits version of the driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor Internet Explorer Slowness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612643/protractor-internet-explorer-slowness)